# Accessing dom elements in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is really a strange question, but let me show the image and then ask.
[image]

as you can see i have a div with id app where all the components are rendered basically.
the project i am working on is using some charts(amcharts) , due to that extra div after the script tags are added and they are taking extra padding, i have searched everywhere but i am not able to solve this.
the one fix or alternative i thought i can use is getElementsByTag and then get the divs which are causing the problem as basically change it styling. I can do that with plain js but not in react component.
I used ref but i can use ref on actual charts but as these divs are not available inside the component how can i add refs to it and access the.

So my question is basically to get the 6 and so divs after the script tag and add some inline styling and remove the width and padding from it.
Hope i am clear.

Comment: " I can do that with plain js but not in react component" if you can do it outside of react then whats the issue?

Comment: all these divs are not available inside index.html file,

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the CSS `~` ([General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)) selector to select the divs and style them.

```css
#app ~ div {
  background: orange;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<script></script>
<script></script>
<script></script>

<div>chart</div>
<div>chart</div>
<div>chart</div>
<div>chart</div>
<div>chart</div>
```